# Mac OSX 10.11 Eclipse JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I've recently updated my mac to OSX 10.11 (el capitan) and opened up eclipse to run a java project that ran fine yesterday before I updated. I received the error message "Error: could not find or load main class Main", and I've narrowed down the problem to eclipse not being able to find the java executable.

Whenever I go to **Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs** it tells me that my old JRE was not found and that it's been deleted. I feel as if this should be as simple as adding a new JRE with the path to my java executable, but here's my problem:

When I run **`which java`** in terminal the output is **`usr/bin/java`**. Using this as the path to my JRE doesn't work... as expected.

So I run **`ls -l which java`** the output is **`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`**
. I Expected this to work, but when I enter this path into eclipse it says the folder does not exist (and I confirmed via terminal, it doesn't exist). I've tried a few other locations in which I find the java executable, but none of them work. I haven't been able to find the correct path to my JRE, which I know is currently installed. How can I find my JRE path?

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking for the wrong thing, I should have just used the install directory of my JDK:

To fix this I typed in terminal: **`/usr/libexec/java_home`** and copied the output (in my case it was **`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home`**) to **`Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs`** within Eclipse. Hope it helps anyone else dealing with this.